# Pass graph property names to gephi using apoc.gephi.add()

Tags: neo4j, cypher, gephi, neo4j-apoc

I am streaming graphs from neo4j to Gephi using the apoc.gephi.add(). The method only passes one property of the node as a node label in Gephi. Which is not only desired node label I want. Is there a way to transfer other property as a node label to Gephi?

For example, My query is as below:

```
MATCH p=(a:Artist)-[r:LOVES]->(b:Artist) WITH p LIMIT 5 
call apoc.gephi.add('http://localhost:8080','workspace2', p) yield nodes, relationships, time
return nodes, relationships, time
```

In the above query, it only shows the names of the artists.

[image]

The above nodes has other properties like type, year_of_work etc. I want to display the other properties too in the node in Gehi. The apoc method only pass one property as node label. Following is the Node table in Gephi.

[image]

So is there a way to pass other properties? Is there any other way to stream a graph in Gephi from neo4j with the desired behavior?

Comment: I tried to add the `properties` yield option but it still didn't work

Answer (score 2):

This functionality was just recently added. You can use:

```
MATCH p=(a:Artist)-[r:LOVES]->(b:Artist) WITH p LIMIT 5 
call apoc.gephi.add('http://localhost:8080','workspace2',p,'weight',['type', 'year_of_work']) yield nodes, relationships, time
return nodes, relationships, time
```

Where fourth parameter can be used to export weight, and fifth parameter as an array of all the properties you want to export from both nodes and relationships. Check [documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_example) for more.

Answer (score 0):

All examples in the [APOC Procedure docs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_streaming_data_to_gephi) show the paths being collected before the apoc.gephi.add call. So try it:

```
MATCH p=(a:Artist)-[r:LOVES]->(b:Artist)
WITH p LIMIT 5 
WITH collect(p) AS ps
call apoc.gephi.add('http://localhost:8080','workspace2', ps) yield nodes, relationships, time
return nodes, relationships, time
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work. I tried that. It shows the same behavior.